# how to use fileManager.unmountVolume in swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

im trying to eject/unmount a usb drive in swift 
i think i have to use fileManager.unmountVolume

```
let urlString = "/Volumes/UNTITLED/".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlUserAllowed)
let url = URL(string: urlString!)

fileManager.unmountVolume(at: url!, options: FileManager.UnmountOptions.init(), completionHandler: {(_) in})
```

wen no drive is plugged in i get no output but wen a drive is plugged in i get `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme`

Answer (score 0):

`urlString` isn't a URL string -- it's a filesystem path. Creating a URL from it using `URL(string:)` results in an incomplete URL.

Use [the `URL(fileUrlWithPath:)` constructor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780183-init) instead to create a `file://` URL. (You don't need to percent-encode a path before passing it to this function.)

Comment: thank you, just to be clear this code is correct? `fileManager.unmountVolume(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Volumes/UNTITLED"), options: FileManager.UnmountOptions.init(), completionHandler: {(_) in})`